# Unable to use word.tokenize() functionc from nltk package

Tags: python, nltk

Unable to call the word_tokenize() from the nltk package. Even though I had performed the following steps in terminal

```
>>python
>>import nltk
>>nltk.download('all')
```

and following is the simple code for tokenizing

```
import nltk
sentence = """At eight o'clock on Thursday morning. Arthur didn't feel very good."""
tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(sentence)
tokens
```

but in spyder console it shows

```
import nltk
File "nltk.py", line 3, in <module>
tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(sentence)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'word_tokenize'
>>>
```

Comment: Try `pip install nltk`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you named your script `nltk.py`, so your code is importing itself instead of the `nltk` module as you expect.

Try changing your script to use another name.

Comment: Hmmm, downvoted for providing the correct answer. Well done whomever.